# Getting Cannot find type 'FirebaseAuth' in scope but FirebaseAuth looks like it's installed

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have a Swift app set up with the Firebase packages installed (I think).

The code is pretty much the exact same as a previous app that I set up. That previous app works fine.

But the new app is giving me "Cannot find type 'FirebaseAuth' in scope" errors all throughout the app.

It's not clear to me what I need to do differently.

The app file looks like this:

```
import SwiftUI
import Firebase

@main
struct MyApp: App {
    @StateObject var viewModel = AuthViewModel()

    init() {
        FirebaseApp.configure()
    }

    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
                .environmentObject(viewModel)
        }
    }
}
```

When I try to add Firebase, the interface seems a bit clumsy to me. I want to check something like a box to specifically point the a specicifc component of Firebase. But XCode does not seem to be set up that way.

Even so, when I look to the bottom left of the Project Manager, I see the packages, and Firebase is there with a subfolder for FirebaseAuth. So it looks to me like it's installed.

But this line causes the error "Cannot find type 'FirebaseAuth' in scope":

```
    @Published var userSession: FirebaseAuth.User?
```

I do not see why FirebaseAuth is not in scope.

Note that I added the GoogleService-Info file to the app. It's in the correct place

Comment: You need to import it

Comment: I added the import statements. That did work.

But it's unclear to me why I need more import statements in one app vs another...

In the first app, I just have:

    import Firebase
    import FirebaseFirestoreSwift

In the second app, I need to have:

import Firebase
import FirebaseFirestore
import FirebaseAuth

The apps are otherwise identical.

Comment: You haven’t provided enough info for that but generally you need to import any parent package in the file that needs it.